# Conditionally loading stylesheet Angular 2

Tags: angular, localization, components, stylesheet

I've a bilingual website en and ar each language have its own stylesheet and I'd like to dynamically load the stylesheet based on the selected language

any idea of how to implement such a requirement by using Angular2?

here is the component decorator

```
@Component({

selector: 'recent-recognition',
template: require('./recent.recognition.component.html'),
styles:
[
    //I want to load only one of these based on if condition
    require('./recent.recognition.component.css'),
    require('./recent.recognition.component.ar.css')
]
})
```

I also have translate.service which contains current language and is referenced in this component successfully.

Answer (score 5):

You could use **DOCUMENT** to switch theme like this-

```
    import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Component({
            selector: 'app-root',
            template: `
              <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" [checked]="theme" (change)="toggleTheme($event)">
                <div class="slider round"></div>
              </label>
            `,
    })

    export class SomeComponent {

    constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

    toggleTheme(e: any) {
    this.theme = !this.theme;

    if(this.theme) {
            this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'condition1.css');
    }
    else {
            this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'condition2.css');
    }

    }
}
```

Reference: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DOCUMENT-let.html

Comment: are the if statements supposed to be in `ngOnInit`?

Comment: I dont understand, you set the href of what kind of tag ? what is the theme element ?